# Specify to Autofac which Named service to resolve

Tags: c#, autofac

I have two different services (Entity Framework contexts) that I inject all over my application and registered as following:

```
builder.Register<WriteContext>().Named("Write");
builder.Register<ReadContext>().Named("Read");
```

Now, I have two different command handlers (I have more than two) and each one gets injected a `DbContext` as following:

```
public class CommandAHandler : ICommandHandler {

    private readonly DbContext context;
    // this handler should get "Write" context
    public CommandAHandler(DbContext context) {
       this.context = context;
    }

}

public class CommandBHandler : ICommandHandler {

    private readonly DbContext context;
    // this handler should get "Read" context
    public CommandBHandler(DbContext context) {
       this.context = context;
    }

}
```

How can I specify to CommandAHandler to get an instance of type "Write" and to CommandBHandler to get an instance of type "Read"? Using, of course, Autofac registration

Comment: If Autofac behaves like Castle, you would make the defined parameter names the same as the registration names - so they would be `readContext` and `writeContext` in both the registration and the parameter.

Comment: It doesn't right now and I am just moving from Castle to Autofac and miss some nice functionalities of Castle already

Comment: In your example you're registering `WriteContext` and `ReadContext` as the types, but the command handlers expect a `DbContext`. Making each one explicit about what kind of context it expects would do it, but maybe this is just in your example..

Comment: @stuartd I am using SOLID and WriteContext and ReadContext are just an example, of course I could specify the type directly if I knew it upfront ...

Comment: @Steven I do understand so I'll extend my contexts using a specific interface which will rely on LSP 
Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) here (and therefore the SOLID principles). You have one 'abstraction' (i.e. `DbContext`) but if you inject the readonly version into a consumer that expects the writable, the application will break. This is a strong indication that you are violating LSP.

The LSP dictates that you have different abstractions for each case. This basically means you should inject ReadContext and WriteContext directly. This will immediately solve your registration problem, because you can define your handlers as:

```
public CommandAHandler(WriteContext context)
public CommandBHandler(ReadContext context)
```

This allows you to simplify your registration to the following:

```
builder.Register<WriteContext>();
builder.Register<ReadContext>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda expression to register handlers into Ioc. For example:

```
builder.Register(c => new CommandAHandler(c.Resolve<WriteContext>()));
builder.Register(c => new CommandBHandler(c.Resolve<ReadContext>()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `WriteContext` and `ReadContext` are registered as `DbContext`:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<CommandAHandler>()
    .WithParameters(
        new[] {
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(DbContext),
                (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<DbContext>("Write")
            )
        });
builder
    .RegisterType<CommandBHandler>()
    .WithParameters(
        new[] {
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(DbContext),
                (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<DbContext>("Read")
            )
        });
```